# Should my Vue plugin that i'm about to publish depend on Vue itself?

Tags: vue.js, npm, package.json

I wrote a Vue (2) plugin and am about to publish it to NPM. The question is should the plugin's `package.json` contain

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.21"
}
```

I'm pretty sure it should because it's clear that the plugin won't work without Vue  itself. But at the same time i'm doubting: who would even try to use Vue plugin without Vue already installed as a project's dependency? And if I don't add it to the dependencies list then how would I be able to specify which versions of Vue the plugin does work with? (For example, if a user uses Vue 2.1.3 and my plugin will only work with versions starting from 2.5.17)

Comment: when i published my [component](https://npmjs.com/package/vueye-datatable) i see in the npm page that it mentions the dependencies and the dev ones

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I can see on GitHub repo that you explicitly provided `"vue": "^2.5.17"`. So I guess your answer is "yes"?

Comment: yes you should to mention the vue version in order to avoid some incompatibilities